# I am trying to understand what exactly is signature query parameter in binance

Tags: api, get, request, httprequest, binance

I am trying to access this endpoint, where `signature` parameter has to be sent as query parameter
https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#current-open-orders-user_data

I am trying to understand what value for that `signature` key should be passed.

Firstly i thought it was secret key binance exchange given. But it was not, because when try to above endpoint it says that :

```
{
    "code": -1022,
    "msg": "Signature for this request is not valid."
}
```

[image]
^Postman

As you can see i passed my secret key as the value for signature key. It is not working. So what am i really missing here ? or do i need to do some transformations to the secret key ? please help me understand it and advance thanks!

Comment: Are you using HMAC SHA256 signature?

Comment: yes @AlexB, thats the one.

Comment: so do i need to hash that or something ?(completely noob here)

Comment: https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/hmac-sha256-online 

I tried using this, but what do i have to pass as plain text ?

could you please provide me by doing the example of above one accessing that endpoint ?

Comment: There might be an error in the way you are encoding the HMAC SHA256 signature. If you post the code it will be easier for us to help. Your question is quite vague. Also it can be any number of reasons. Are you using the api key for testnet not realnet? if you google your question there are a number of answers dealing with this error message. For example https://dev.binance.vision/t/faq-signature-for-this-request-is-not-valid/176 Also what programming language are you planning to use to call the api? This is where you do the HMAC SHA256 signature encryption.

Comment: I am doing it in C++, but before experimenting there it i always test in postman. and yes my api key definitely matches the API key. and secret key is testnet one. what i am really confused is when hashing, there are two things to be passed right ? first one is a string (which i dont know what to put here) and second one is secret key (which is my testnet secret key)

Comment: *secret key matches API key

Comment: The string is the data that you need to hash with your secret key. Here is a binance string example `symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1499827319559`  which i've taken from https://github.com/binance/binance-signature-examples

Comment: Hey thanks for replying! and Yes i saw that, https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#current-open-orders-user_data

if i were to access this endpoint and my string would be like this ```timestamp=time&recvWIndow=60000``` , then those two parameters dont need to be send as query paramters ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244736/discussion-between-dopller-and-alex-b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are putting the `timestamp` before the `recvWindow` in your query string.

`timestamp` is always the last parameter and the order of the parameters in the [docs](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#current-open-orders-user_data) clearly puts `recvWindow` before `timestamp`.

I managed to get it working with query string `recvWindow=60000&timestamp=1652512756366`

Answer (score 0):

Secret key and signature are two different things.

You need to sign the parameters with your secret key. This process produces a signature. And then you pass this resulting signature to the payload.

I'm not sure how to produce the signature in C++, however [Binance docs](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#signed-trade-user_data-and-margin-endpoint-security) show an example of signing the data in console with `openssl` (scroll right on all 3 examples).

Comment: so if i were to access this https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#current-open-orders-user_data 

then string would be ```&timestamp=time&recvWindow=60000``` ?

because those are the mandatory paramters for that endpoint

Comment: @dopller Without the first `&` sign. Then it should work.

Comment: if i use that string to hash it, then i shouldnt pass those two as query paramters again ? just the signature query paramter is enough ?

Comment: @dopller You also need to pass the params as part of the URL query... By the way, signing and hashing are also two separate things. A signature can be verified asymmetrically with a public key (i.e. Binance does not need to know your secret key to check if the signature is valid), a hash is just a one-way function that can be only verified using the same input.

Comment: So i hashed it using the string ```timestamp=1652457909468&recvWindow=60000``` and my secret key.
```GET https://testnet.binance.vision/api/v3/openOrders?recvWindow=60000&timestamp=1652457909468&signature=c2080b80dd29c73c73ef3cb747781025939651811d1512eb398da646d085d81e```

This is how it looks like, but still it showing me signature for this request is not valid

Comment: @dopller Can you check this? I retyped the secret key from the screenshot, might have a typo (please post it in a form that can be copy-pasted), but got a different signature. `echo -n "timestamp=1652457909468&recvWindow=60000" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "uTe3Ux38L2qgUuhweADYP8rELVUb7ZM3tFzwByyVPeFwMTY9UgUqQA7uD6waDPUH"` resulting in `6da4fd9f455bbc770104ef55b959e98697f5c42eadcf2ad65e901250e7672163`

Comment: thanks, yes i tried hashing thru that method, but still it says that signature for this request is not valid...

Comment: @dopller Then I'm out of ideas for now. Will comment later if I think of something.

Comment: Will try to replicate in postman over the weekend. Not familiar with postman so will have to set it up first. Let us know if you figure it out though.

Comment: @dopller so I managed to get it working with query string `recvWindow=60000&timestamp=1652512756366` I'm not sure why you are putting the `timestamp` before the `recvWindow` in your query string since `timestamp` is always the last parameter and the order of the parameter in the docs clearly puts  `recvWindow` before `timestamp` ? https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#current-open-orders-user_data

Comment: WOW, didnt thought of that! it worked!! thanks a ton sir, really appreciate it for doing this and sorry for your time.

Comment: @dopller you’re welcome. I posted the solution as a new answer so you can accept the correct answer for greater accuracy.

Comment: yeah i did, and @PetrHejda i have learned from your answer as well, thanks for that! and sorry for unaccepting the answer.

Comment: No worries, and thank you Alex for finding the solution! :)